# TLD and subdomain

Tags: subdomain, tld

`.com` or `.net` is a Top Level Domain (TLD). Let's say I have `example.com`, `example` is a subdomain of `.com`. So if I'm buying `example.com` I actually buy subdomain `example`.

In other words the registrar only providing paid service of `.com` subdomain because I'm buying `example` subdomain and I'm not buying the `.com` domain itself.

So that's mean I'm just buying a subdomain from the registrar. Do I understand it correctly? Does any information I provided is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theory is right, but no one actually makes that distinction :) The DNS system is a tree, there's a ROOT domain that is nameless, represented by a single dot. So `example.com` is really `example.com.`

A DNS tree is like this:

```
.
.com
.example
.www
```

Each name to the right on a full DNS address (like `www.example.com`) is a subdomain of the left one, but since the TLDs are regulated you need a registrar to make it resolvable for other people.

So, you are correct, but no one says that.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Isn't that misleading for the registrar to advertise selling .com domain when they actually selling subdomain.

Comment: It's just terminology. Since you can't be found on the outside world without at least `domain.tld` they call it a domain. Calling it subdomain would just cause confusion.